# Laravel 8 - Foreign key constraint failed when ID using startingValue()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to make the `id` start from a certain value. It's working fine when I don't specify the `startingValue(1000)`

This is my products table schema

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id()->startingValue(1000);
    $table->foreignId('store_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->float('price');
    $table->string('specification');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is my favorites table schema

```
Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignIdFor(Product::class)->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreignIdFor(User::class)->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

It gives me this error
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: Ok, just a tip: If you create the table normally, and insert 1 record with id 999. then next record will have id 1000(tested on mysql/mariadb). Maybe you can resolve it like this :)

Comment: Sorry, i'll edit it

Comment: @RobBiermann maybe that will work, but i don't a 'hacky' way if possible

Comment: Create a seeder that make a record with `id` of 999